# How do you guard for Null Reference exceptions in Linq To Xml?

Tags: xml, linq, exception, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages> 
  <page id="56">
    <img id="teaser" src="img/teaser_company.png"></img>
  </page>  
</pages>
```

I have an xml file that defines additional resources for pages within a cms. What's the best way to guard for Null Reference exceptions when querying this file with LinqToXml?

```
var page = (from tabElement in extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
where tabElement.Attribute("id").Value == tabId.ToString()
select tabElement).SingleOrDefault();
```

This code could potentially trigger a Null Reference exception if a page element doesn't have an attribute called "id". Do I have to use a try catch block or is there a way to handle this? For instance return null for page the page object if there's no attribute called "id" for the page element.

Comment: How about checking upfront the tabId?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EDIT: This was clearly written a long time ago - these days I'd definitely go with the cast as per Igor's answer.

The simplest way would be something like:

```
var page = (from tabElement in extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
            let idAttribute = tabElement.Attribute("id")
            where idAttribute != null 
                  && idAttribute.Value == tabId.ToString()
            select tabElement).SingleOrDefault();
```

Alternatively you could write an extension method to `XElement`:

```
public static string AttributeValueOrDefault(this XElement element,
                                             string attributeName)
{
    XAttribute attr = element.Attribute(attributeName);
    return attr == null ? null : attr.Value;
}
```

then use:

```
var page = (from element in extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
            where element.AttributeValueOrDefault("id") == tabId.ToString()
            select element).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or to use dot notation:

```
var page = extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
             .Where(x => x.AttributeValueOrDefault("id") == tabId.ToString())
             .SingleOrDefault();
```

(It would make sense to call `tabId.ToString()` once beforehand, btw, rather than for every iteration.)

Comment: The extension method will only work if you don't need a property of the attribute, like its length. `x.AttributeValueOrDefault("id").Length > 0` for instance will still throw a NullReferenceException. I think using `let` is safer. _BTW, unfortunately ReSharper doesn't warn about a possible NullReferenceEception if you use_ `let` _and don't check for_ `null`.

Comment: @comecme: In that case you could use the null-coalescing operator. It wasn't meant to be a panacea... although using the explicit cast would actually be better here.

Answer (score 10):

In .NET 4 LINQ to XML provides a way to do that and it is through using [explicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx):

```
var page = (
  from tabElement in extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
    where (string)tabElement.Attribute("id") == tabId.ToString()
    select tabElement
).SingleOrDefault();
```

If the attribute is not there, then the result will simply be null.

In addition to explicit `string` operator there are also most of the primitive types and their Nullable versions. This means that you can do `AttributeOrDefault` using this kind of syntax:

```
//<element theAttr="12" />
int theAttr = (int?)doc.Element("element").Attribute("missingAttr") ?? 0;
```

Comment: Your last example could case a NullReferenceException if no Element `"element"` exists.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen other people use a straight cast to a string before as well; I don't know if it's any more or less efficient than what Jon suggested, but I quite like the syntax.

```
var page = extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
             .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == tabId.ToString())
             .SingleOrDefault();
```

Anyone feel free to fix that if there's some flaw in my thinking; I'm quite new to LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use XPath expressions where the code would otherwise be cluttered with lots of null checks. For your example:

```
var query = string.Format("page[@id='{0}']", tabId.ToString());
var page = extensionsDoc.XPathSelectElement(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class entity mapping the XML element. And call a method that would check null value. I use this method in my code, it works fine. Hope it helps.

Here is a sample code to adjust depending on your needs :

```
private void Method1(...) {
    ...

    var pages = from tabElement in extensionsDoc.Descendants("page")
    where tabElement.Attribute("id").Value == tabId.ToString()
    select new Page {
                imgSrc = Method2(tabElement)
            };

    // pages variable is a List<Page> object
    ...
}

private void Method2(XElement element) {
    XElement img = element.Element("img");

    if (img != null) {
        ...
        // TODO return the imgSrc
        return "";
    }

    // return null or ""
    return null;
}
```

Then the Page class definition :

```
class Page
{
    public string imgSrc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If `tabElement` doesn't have an attribute `"id"`, that would still cause a NullReferenceException in your `Method1`.